# What does site_name & site_url by connection to tableau sever mean?

Tags: python, tableau-api

Hello dear community!

I need to write (my first) python script, which should download many views from one tableau dashboard and then save it in one excel-file. I have a problem with the connection to the tableau server with tableau-api-lib. I found this code and have a question:

```
from tableau_api_lib import TableauServerConnection
from tableau_api_lib.utils.querying import get_projects_dataframe

tableau_server_config = {
        'my_env': {
                'server': 'https://YourTableauServer.com',
                'api_version': '<YOUR_API_VERSION>',
                'username': '<YOUR_USERNAME>',
                'password': '<YOUR_PASSWORD>',
                'site_name': '<YOUR_SITE_NAME>',
                'site_url': '<YOUR_SITE_CONTENT_URL>'
        }
}

conn = TableauServerConnection(tableau_server_config, env='my_env')
conn.sign_in()
```

What means site_name and site_url? Is it the url of dashboard? If not, how to find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

The site url id can be ""

Password can be entered between the quotes, no {} needed

Ignore the personal access token portion

I am going to guess that the version is 3.11 as well

You can ignore everything after "if use_pat_flag"

```
# This example shows how to use the Tableau Server REST API
# to sign in to a server, get back an authentication token and
# site ID, and then sign out.
# The example runs in Python 2.7 and Python 3.3 code

import requests, json


# NOTE! Substitute your own values for the following variables
use_pat_flag = False  # True = use personal access token for sign in, false = use username and password for sign in.

server_name = "YOUR_SERVER"   # Name or IP address of your installation of Tableau Server
version = "3.11"     # API version of your server
site_url_id = ""    # Site (subpath) to sign in to. An empty string is used to specify the default site.

# For username and password sign in
user_name = "USERNAME"    # User name to sign in as (e.g. admin)
password = "{PASSWORD}"

# For Personal Access Token sign in
personal_access_token_name = "TOKEN_NAME"          # Name of the personal access token.
personal_access_token_secret = "TOKEN_VALUE"   # Value of the token.

signin_url = "https://{server}/api/{version}/auth/signin".format(server=server_name, version=version)

if use_pat_flag:
    # The following code constructs the body for the request.
    # The resulting element will look similar to the following example:
    #
    # {
    #    "credentials": {
    #        "personalAccessTokenName": "TOKEN_NAME",
    #        "personalAccessTokenSecret": "TOKEN_VALUE",
    #        "site": {
    #          "contentUrl": ""
    #        }
    #     }
    # }
    #

    payload = { "credentials": { "personalAccessTokenName": personal_access_token_name, "personalAccessTokenSecret": personal_access_token_secret, "site": {"contentUrl": site_url_id }}}

    headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }

else:
    # The following code constructs the body for the request. The resulting element will# look similar to the following example:
    #
    #
    # {
    #    "credentials": {
    #        "name": "USERNAME",
    #        "password": "PASSWORD",
    #        "site": {
    #          "contentUrl": ""
    #        }
    #     }
    # }
    #

    payload = { "credentials": { "name": user_name, "password": password, "site": {"contentUrl": site_url_id }}}

    headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }

# Send the request to the server
req = requests.post(signin_url, json=payload, headers=headers, verify=False)
req.raise_for_status()

# Get the response
response = json.loads(req.content)

# Parse the response JSON. The response body will look similar
# to the following example:
#
# {
#    "credentials": {
#        "site": {
#            "id": "xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
#            "contentUrl": ""
#        },
#        "user": {
#            "id": "xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"
#        },
#         "token": "CREDENTIALS_TOKEN"
#    }
# }
#

# Get the authentication token from the credentials element
token = response["credentials"]["token"]

# Get the site ID from the <site> element
site_id = response["credentials"]["site"]["id"]

print('Sign in successful!')
print('\tToken: {token}'.format(token=token))
print('\tSite ID: {site_id}'.format(site_id=site_id))

# Set the authentication header using the token returned by the Sign In method.
headers['X-tableau-auth']=token



# ... Make other calls here ...


# Sign out
signout_url = "https://{server}/api/{version}/auth/signout".format(server=server_name, version=version)

req = requests.post(signout_url, data=b'', headers=headers, verify=False)
req.raise_for_status()
print('Sign out successful!')
```

Comment: Thank you @smitty_werben_jagerm I write 'site_name': '',
                'site_url': '' and it works